# What do you call the way a culture is forming their language?

Tags: linguistics, sociolinguistics

suppose a culture is still starting to be develop and they are forming their "language" for communication? what do you call this process?

Regards,

Comment: This question isn't specifically about the English language and might be more on-topic at https://linguistics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Might also fit on [worldbuilding.se]? Or (@the-wolf) is this about emergence of a new cultural and linguistic gestalt in seceded / newly independent areas (e.g. Montenegro)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about English Language & Usage.

Answer (score 1):

The formation of a new language is referred to in the literature as the "emergence" of a language. Such a thing, though, is incredibly rare and often disputed (see Nicaraguan sign language as an example). Creolisation is much more common. Dialect formation is a different matter.